# How to call a function from moonscript in lua?

Tags: lua, moonscript, lua-loadfile

I've got a moon script code like this:

```
hello = (name) ->
  print "Hello #{name}!"
```

And i want to use it in my lua code using `moonscript.loadfile`

how should i do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MoonScript code compiles to Lua, so the function you've written is actually a Lua function when it's being executed.

There are a few ways to get access to it in Lua:

- Compile the file ahead of time using the `moonc` command line tool. This will give you a a `.lua` file that you can load as you would any other Lua file.
- Load the file using one of the MoonScript loader function. `moonscript.loadfile` is a lower level function, and I don't recommend using it unless that's what you specifically need. The easiest way is to call `require "moonscript"` in your program, then Lua's `require` function is augmented to be able to load MoonScript files directly. There's more information on the [Compiler API reference page](http://moonscript.org/reference/api.html).

Keep in mind that if you have function in another file, you need to export them as part of the module. You do this by having a return value for the module. The typically pattern is to return a table that contains all the function you would want to use. In MoonScript, the last line in a file is automatically converted into a return statement. Assignment is no coerced into a return though, so I recommend structuring your module like this:

```
hello = (name) ->
  print "Hello #{name}!"

{:hello}
```